# How to set the application database to be used by Resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redis, resque

I have a Rails application running with Resque, but I'm facing a problem when running it on production environment.

The application runs using development's database. How can I set the database to be used by Resque according to application environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When starting the Rails server, you should also provide the environment:

```
rails server -e production
```

Comment: Yeah, I did it. But it stills choosing the development database =/

Comment: Can you post your configuration file, where you define the database to be used?